# SQL Server 2012 - updating with a twist

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

Based on data I do not control, I was able to determine three row sets of data based on last names provided within the data.

```
BEG    END

AAA    GYS
HA     OUN
OUR    ZZZ
```

As you can see, the second row set starts with **HA** (the **BEG** column).  What I would like is to update 2nd row set **BEG** column value from **HA** to **GYT**, which is the **END** value of the 1st row set plus the next 3 alpha character combination group in line.  In the same turn, I would like to update the 3rd row set **BEG** column value from **OUR** to **OUO**, which is the **END** value of the 2nd row set plus the next 3 alpha character combination in line.

Now, this is just and example, I could have only anywhere from two to ten starting row sets, but the script must be intelligent enough to handle all circumstances.

I created a table with all the 3 alpha combinations, AAA - ZZZ, 17,576 rows in all, thinking I could use this table to determine what to update to, but I cannot logically figure out how to make a smart script to handle all potential revisions.

Any ideas?

Comment: For consistency with standard terminology, don't say "group", say "row." Group has a specific meaning in SQL which is different from what you are referring to. Also, instead of imbedding a screenshot, it is standard practice on this site to imbed a text representation of the sample data set. Please edit your post and make these improvements.

Comment: Is it always 3 chars in the `end` column?

Comment: Good questions...  As the BEG can be 2 characters, I would assume that there could be situations where the END could be 2 characters as well.  In those cases I would append a underscore character. Such as HO_.

Comment: And to what the underscore need to be changed?

Comment: If END was HO_,  that would be updated to HOA.  the next row set BEG would be HOB.

Comment: Are you sure about that underscore? What, then, does a `Z` advance to? A blank, as in `HA` from the sample data? (Or is that really `HA `, with a trailing space?) What if one of your `END` values _is_ `HA`? Does that advance to `HA_`, `HAA`, or something else all together?

Comment: Actually, I was asked to append an 'A' to make up the missing characters.  So 'HO' becomes 'HOA'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the fact that you already have the `aaa`-`zzz` table and assuming all `end` values exists in the letters table, - one solution could be to use an updatable cte.

Setup: create and populate the letters table (well, partially, only the letters needed for the demo)

```
DECLARE @Letters As TABLE
(
    Alpha char(3)
)

INSERT INTO @Letters (Alpha) VALUES
('AAA'), ('AAB'), ('AAC'), /*...*/ ('AAZ'), ('ABA'), ('ABB') -- ....
('GYS'), ('GYT'), -- ....
('OUN'), ('OUO'), -- ....
('RSZ'), ('RTA') -- ....
```

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    Beg char(3),
    [End] char(3)
);

INSERT INTO @T (Beg, [End]) VALUES
('AAA', 'GYS'),
('HA', 'OUN'),
('ST', 'ZZZ');
```

The cte:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT Beg, [End], LAG([End]) OVER(ORDER BY Beg) As LastEnd
    FROM @T
)
```

The update statement:

```
UPDATE CTE
SET Beg = (SELECT TOP 1 Alpha FROM @Letters WHERE Alpha > LastEnd ORDER BY Alpha)
FROM CTE 
WHERE LastEnd IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Zohar, both for a solution, and instruction on providing data when asking questions to get assist me with answers.